# How can I dynammicaly create an object inside a object, on a array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-object

How do I dynamically create an object inside another object?

I got this code:

```
var lista = [{
        "product": "Dipers",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "product": "Beear",
        "quantity": 6
    },
    {
        "product": "Bread",
        "quantity": 10
    }
];
```

But I need to add new objects so it'll look something like this:

```
var lista = [{
        "product": "Dipers",
        "quantity": 2

        seller1 = {
        "name": "B&J",
        "adress": "that street"
        }
        seller2 = {
        "name": "B&J",
        "adress": "that street"
        }

    },
    {
        "product": "Beear",
        "quantity": 6
    },
    {
        "product": "Bread",
        "quantity": 10
    }
];
```

---

How would I add `seller1` and `seller2` dynamically to the existing object `lista`?

Comment: The second example is not a valid js object. `seller = {}`

Comment: Do you have a list of sellers and how do you know which seller belongs to who?

Comment: @kemicofa I would have a input field, where I would get the data, of the name and of the adress and would save like that.

Comment: @kemicofa sorry I don't really know to make a valid object inside that, that's why I was asking, ty anyways for replaying.

Comment: @MiguelRodrigues change `=` to `:` for inner `seller1` and `seller2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the new object properties that you wrote/retrieved to a new variable and then simply use *dot notation* to retrieve the new properties and assign it to your object.

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I described above:

```js
var lista = [{
        "product": "Dipers",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "product": "Beear",
        "quantity": 6
    },
    {
        "product": "Bread",
        "quantity": 10
    }
];

let newObj = {
  "seller1": {
    "name": "B&J",
    "adress": "that street"
  },
  "seller2": {
    "name": "B&J",
    "adress": "that street"
  }
}

lista[0].seller1 = newObj.seller1;
lista[0].seller2 = newObj.seller2;

console.log(lista);
```

---

**N.B.** An object property uses the colon `:` and not the equal sign `=`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the sellers in an array and later use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var lista = [{
        "product": "Dipers",
        "quantity": 2

        sellers:[{
        "name": "B&J",
        "adress": "that street"
        },
        {
        "name": "B&J",
        "adress": "that street"
        }]

    },
    {
        "product": "Beear",
        "quantity": 6
    },
    {
        "product": "Bread",
        "quantity": 10
    }
];
```

Then, in your code, dynamically add a seller:

```
lista[desiredindex].sellers.push({name:"new",address:"new"});
```

Comment: `lista[0].sellers.push(/* ... */)`

Comment: `list[desiredindex].sellers.push(values)`

Comment: So if I made push the seller's array would increment every time I tried to push a seller, or it would be a fixed size, the 2 sellers was just an example, I need it in every field. @kemicofa

Comment: @MiguelRodrigues Arrays in js objects aren't fixed-length. you can add as many as you want. You can do this to every property you want, just change it from a `"string"` value to an `array`

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code, but as I understand you need this

```
 const seller1Name = “seller1”;
 const seller2Name = “seller2”;
 const lista = [{
    "product": "Dipers",
    "quantity": 2
   },
   {
    "product": "Beear",
    "quantity": 6
   },
   {
    "product": "Bread",
    "quantity": 10
   }
 ];
 lista[0][seller1Name] = {
   "name": "B&J",
   "adress": "that street"
 }

 lista[0][seller2Name] = {
     "name": "B&J",
     "adress": "that street"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this..

```
var lista = [{
        "product": "Dipers",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "product": "Beear",
        "quantity": 6
    },
    {
        "product": "Bread",
        "quantity": 10
    }
];
///  try this


lista[0]['seller1']={
        "name": "B&J",
        "adress": "that street"
        };
lista[0]['seller2']={
        "name": "B&J",
        "adress": "that street"
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

As was answered above by SomoKRoceS, you can do your script this way:

```
var lista = [{
        "product": "Dipers",
        "quantity": 2,
        "sellers": []
    },
    {
        "product": "Beear",
        "quantity": 6,
        "sellers": []
    },
    {
        "product": "Bread",
        "quantity": 10,
        "sellers": []
    }
];

var seller1 = {
    "name": "B&J",
  "adress": "that street"
}

var seller2 = {
    "name": "Test",
  "adress": "that street"
}

lista[0].sellers.push(seller1);
lista[1].sellers.push(seller2);
lista[2].sellers.push(seller1);
lista[2].sellers.push(seller2);

console.log(lista);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ar58teo/